# Unsubscribe em Observable com Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

Olá

Preciso de ajuda em um problema que está ocorrendo comigo. Tenho um código pra ficar escutando mudanças no banco de dados do firebase. Sendo assim, tenho que fazer subscribe em uma observable que me trás os dados do BD.
Porém, quando eu excluir esse objeto que está sendo monitorado preciso fazer o unsubscribe, porém, antes de excluí o objeto. Senão é disparado um erro do tipo **firebase error missing or insufficient permissions**.
Pensei na possibilidade de capturar somente o erro desse tipo (Firebase error insuficient permission). Isso já seria uma solução pra mim, porém, não sei como fazer o unsubscribe dentro do catchError do rxjs(não sei nem se é possível).
Veja que os dois takeUntil tem um notifier que são diferentes. O primeiro uso para quando o usuário fazer logout e o segundo para quando o usuário sai da página. Não posso usa-los porque são muitos objetos que usa esse mesmo subscribe e se eu aplicar this.appState.onDestroy.next() ou this.onDestroy.next() quando excluir **um objeto** eu desativarei o valueChanges dos outros objetos. Como proceder?

Código abaixo:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap, takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AppStateService} from '../service/app-state.service';

export abstract class processor implements OnDestroy {


  ShopSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  onDestroy: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  data: any;
  protected constructor(
    protected appState: AppStateService
  ) {
 
     this.ShopSubject
      .pipe(switchMap(id => {
        return this.shopService.docValueChanges(`shop/${id}`);
      }))
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.appState.onDestroy))
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data= data;
      });
    }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onDestroy.next();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu de fato não entendi muito em qual situação você gostaria de cancelar a subscrição do valueChanges ao deletar o mesmo documento. não faz sentido pois quando acontece ele passa a não emitir mais. sobre desescrever pode ver as dicas a baixo.

O ideal na maioria das situações é nunca necessitar subscrever ao observable dentro do código do componente e usar ela diretamente no template utilizando o async pipe.
Ao utilizar esta técnica o angular automaticamente lhe da com o unsubscribe.

```
    export abstract class Processor {
        ShopSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
        data: Observable<any>;

        protected constructor(protected appState: AppStateService) {
            this.data = this.ShopSubject.pipe(
                switchMap(id => this.shopService.docValueChanges(`shop/${id}`))
            );
        }
    }
```

no template use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data | async as mydata">
    seu html...
<ng-container>
```

Caso você ainda precise utilizar o subscribe dentro do código do componente use:

```
export abstract class Processor implements OnDestroy {
        ShopSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
        data: any;
        mySubscription: Subscription;
    
        protected constructor(protected appState: AppStateService) {
            this.mySubscription = this.ShopSubject.pipe(
                    switchMap(id => this.shopService.docValueChanges(`shop/${id}`))
                )
        .subscribe(data => this.data= data);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

extrapolando a situação.
caso sua situação de observar pela exclusão do elemento
você pode utilizar um novo observable com stateChanges(['removed']) ao invés do valueChanges.
e para executar coisas antes de sair da pagina vc pode até utilizar o CanDeactivate do Router para executar uma lógica.